# Reorganizing XML to another XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to convert Students.xml in which data of each student is given, to Courses.xml in which this data is organised per course.
I am able to achieve it partly when I have one course per student however if more than one course per student is provided, the result is all wrong. Is there a way through which I can get all the courses name in an array and then loop through on basis of these values inside my xsl file?

**Students.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Students>
  <Student>
    <name>A</name>
    <rollNo>1</rollNo>
    <course>Music</course>
    <course>Computers</course>
 </Student>
 <Student>
    <name>B</name>
    <rollNo>2</rollNo>
    <course>Sports</course>
 </Student>
 <Student>
    <name>C</name>
    <rollNo>3</rollNo>
    <course>Sports</course>
            <course>Music</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>D</name>
    <rollNo>4</rollNo>
    <course>GK</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>E</name>
    <rollNo>5</rollNo>
    <course>Computers</course>
            <course>Maths</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>F</name>
    <rollNo>6</rollNo>
    <course>Physics</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>G</name>
    <rollNo>7</rollNo>
    <course>Drama</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>H</name>
    <rollNo>8</rollNo>
    <course>Communication</course>
            <course>Computers</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>I</name>
    <rollNo>9</rollNo>
    <course>Arts</course>
</Student>
<Student>
    <name>J</name>
    <rollNo>10</rollNo>
    <course>Computers</course>
</Student>  
</Students>
```

**Transform.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="students-by-course" match="Student" use="course" />
<xsl:template match="Students">
<Courses>
<xsl:for-each select = "Student[count(. | key('students-by-course',    course)[1]) = 1]">
<xsl:sort select="course" />
<course>
 <name>
   <xsl:value-of select="course"/>
 </name>
   <xsl:for-each select="key('students-by-course', course)">
<Student>
<name>
  <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</name>
<rollNo>
  <xsl:value-of select="rollNo"/>
</rollNo>
</Student>
</xsl:for-each>
</course>
</xsl:for-each>
</Courses>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This gives me following Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Courses>
 <course>
    <name>Arts</name>
    <Student>
        <name>I</name>
        <rollNo>9</rollNo>
    </Student>
 </course>
 <course>
    <name>Drama</name>
    <Student>
        <name>G</name>
        <rollNo>7</rollNo>
    </Student>
 </course>
 <course>
    <name>GK</name>
    <Student>
        <name>D</name>
        <rollNo>4</rollNo>
    </Student>
 </course>
 <course>
    <name>Music</name>
    <Student>
        <name>A</name>
        <rollNo>1</rollNo>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <name>C</name>
        <rollNo>3</rollNo>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <name>E</name>
        <rollNo>5</rollNo>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <name>H</name>
        <rollNo>8</rollNo>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <name>J</name>
        <rollNo>10</rollNo>
    </Student>
 </course>
 <course>
    <name>Physics</name>
    <Student>
        <name>F</name>
        <rollNo>6</rollNo>
    </Student>
 </course>
 <course>
    <name>Sports</name>
    <Student>
        <name>B</name>
        <rollNo>2</rollNo>
    </Student>
    <Student>
        <name>C</name>
        <rollNo>3</rollNo>
    </Student>
</course>
</Courses>
```

As one can see result is all wrong. Some courses are not even listed e.g. Computers and some students info is assigned to wrong courses. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: This is a *grouping* problem. If you're using  XSLT 1.0, start here: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k I am new to xslt. I tried the link and I got partial solution for it. However if I specify multiple courses per student, the result is incorrect. e.g. Student A is enrolled in course1 and course2 and Student B is enrolled in course2. In the output I am getting both students under course1 and no listing for course2. Ideally Course1 should have StudentA and Course2 should have both the students. can you help?

Comment: You need to group your `Student` nodes by `course`. Then, under each unique `course`, list the students in that group. If you still can't make it work, post your attempt so we can fix it.

Comment: Note also that grouping is much easier in XSLT 2.0, using the xsl:for-each-group instruction.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I tried to look for the syntax support for the same. I edited my question with my current xsl file. Can you help me with some directions on how to group by 'course'

Comment: What's wrong with the result you're getting now?

Comment: It does not support multiple courses per student. It is giving me wrong result If I attempt to do so.

Comment: I think you are mistaken about that. In the given example, there are no students with multiple courses. Please edit your question to show an input where some students have multiple courses, and add the result you expect.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I edited the question and shared my current output as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought you would have a separate `Student` element for each enrollment of a student in a course. Otherwise what does the `rollNo` represent?

Anyway, with the structure you now show, your stylesheet should look like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="course" match="course" use="." />

<xsl:template match="Students">
    <Courses>
        <xsl:for-each select="Student/course[count(. | key('course', .)[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:sort select="." />
            <course>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </name>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('course', .)">
                    <Student>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="../name | ../rollNo"/>
                    </Student>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </course>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Courses>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks. It solved my problem. Can you provide me some links where I can read more about such grouping problems in xslt.

Comment: I am afraid I don't know. But you can learn a lot from the examples posted here on SO.